# Create glowing Stars with emitting Light Rays (Blender 2.8)

Tags: light, eevee-render-engine

I am an absolute beginner in blender and I am using 2.8 beta.
I want to create some glowing stars who look like they emit light rays.

Something like this

[image]

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You could do it by the Compositor

Comment: Could you describe it in more detail. I have never worked in the compositor before.